# error trying to access core data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to get the values I have saved in one of my core data objects, however I keep getting this error

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Man''
```

The resulted error is occurring from the code I have written that tries to access the core data object then logg its content, as show shown below.

```
if ([manufDBVNumber isEqualToNumber:currentDBVersion]) {
        // READ FROM CORE DATA
        // WRITE TO CORE DATA
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSLog(@"%@", context);

        // Test listing all FailedBankInfos from the store
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Man" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; // This is where the error is happening.
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSError *error;


        NSMutableArray *manufacturerDictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (Manuf *manuf in fetchedObjects) {
            NSLog(@"MANA: %@", man.mana);
            NSLog(@"SURGE: %@", man.surge);
            NSLog(@"HEALTH: %@", manuf.health);


etc//....
```

This is how I have synthesized the managedObjectContext and fetchedResultsController

```
// Core-Data variables used for fetching and managing the object
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You do this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

But then you access this:

```
self.managedObjectContext
```

Assuming your `NSLog(@"%@", context);` shows a valid NSManagedObjectContext, then I would do this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Man" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Or, change your original declaration to:

```
self.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: When I change it to **contect** this is the error I am getting.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Man''*** And where I NSLog Context It is just logging back **(null)**

Comment: Well, there's one of your problems. [self managedObjectContext] is returning null. How did you implement that method? Do you ever actually set self.managedObjectContext?

Comment: Okay so I found out the issue, This is what was buzzing me out, I was already using this same coredata object but for some reason it wasnt working in this view.. I thought maybe it way my code but actually It's because I have only decleared it to work in the one "other view".. Do you have any idea how to make it work in both views?

Comment: You have to pass the object. It is very common and if you look at Apple's sample code you can see how they do it. Easiest way is when you create your view you set the managedObjectContext property.

Comment: yes, I am doing that now.. but I am trying to access this in two different views I was now woundering what the best way to do this would be?

Comment: "yes, I am doing that now" - apparently not, or your code would work. If you are doing it, then access it like this: NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Man" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

Answer (score 1):

In your viewController.m implementation file, right under this bit of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
```

add this bit of code:

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, Rawls Enterprises. I've been struggling with this same problem for more hours than I will admit and your simple line of code has cured the problem for good. Have I said thank you?